# When do you need to use self in a nested function?

Tags: python, nested, self

Why do we need to use `self` for `ans`, but not `min1` in the following code (via LeetCode)?

```
def findSecondMinimumValue(self, root):
    self.ans = float('inf')
    min1 = root.val

    def dfs(node):
        if node:
            if min1 < node.val < self.ans:
                self.ans = node.val
            elif node.val == min1:
                dfs(node.left)
                dfs(node.right)

    dfs(root)
    return self.ans if self.ans < float('inf') else -1
```

Comment: `min1` is a local variable and `ans` is an attribute of `self` because you created them that way.

Comment: @khelwood This is a solution from leetcode and my question is why we need self for ans but not for min1? If I take away self from ans the code will not run correctly.

Comment: @wjandrea Oops, I meant instance method *facepalm*

Comment: @AMC Oh, haha! I see what you mean though: the class definition is missing.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, and it's important information.

Answer (score 1):

`min1` is local to the function body. Its name only exists within the body of `findSecondMinimumValue()`. Once your code exits that function, min1 won't be available for use.

`ans` is an attribute that belongs to the class instance and has to be accessed through `self`. If you created two different instances of whatever class this method is a part of, that would mean each instance has its own version of `self.ans`, `self` being a name that refers to the instance that calls the method and `self.ans` therefore referring to an instance's `ans` attribute.

As an example:

```
class Example:
    foo = "CLASS attribute"

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "INSTANCE attribute"
```

```
a = Example()
b = Example()
a.bar = "INSTANCE attribute changed"
print(a.bar) # -> "INSTANCE attribute changed"
print(b.bar) # -> "INSTANCE attribute" because changing a.bar doesn't affect b.bar

Example.foo = "CLASS attribute changed"
print(a.foo == b.foo) # -> True
```

Comment: You're very close, but `ans` is an *attribute* of the instance, not a variable. Instances don't have variables per se.

Comment: Gotcha, wasn't sure about the exact naming of it. Corrected the post.

Comment: Better, but it's still a bit off. Attributes don't have scope; they're attached to an object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is much simpler. You're recursively changing `self.ans`. That's why, if you don't use `self`, you have to define and pass an extra variable, I guess.

Just another version, which'd pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def findSecondMinimumValue(self, root):
        self.second = float('inf')

        def traverse(node):
            if not node:
                return

            if root.val < node.val < self.second:
                self.second = node.val

            traverse(node.left)
            traverse(node.right)

        traverse(root)
        return -1 if self.second == float('inf') else self.second
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-minimum-node-in-a-binary-tree/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.